# Alert in if/else statement in React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, validation, react-hooks

I'm trying to validate phone number input in the React JS component by using if/else statement. I would like to show a message("please check phone number") if the user types letters instead of numbers. So far, I was able to create a function, that checks if the input value is numbers only, but I can't figure out how to show the message alert(like in Bootstrap/reactstrap) if the user inputs letters.

[link to codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-zo5x6?file=/src/App.js:1-653)

My code is

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Alert } from "reactstrap";


export default () => {
const [number, setNumber] = useState(" ");

const numberHandleChange = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        const re = /^[0-9\b]+$/;
        if (e.target.value === "" || re.test(e.target.value)) {
            setNumber(e.target.value);
            console.log(e.target.value);
        } else {
            alert("please check your phone number");
        }
  };

  return(

<label htmlFor="phone">
                        <h5>Phone</h5>
                        <input
                            type="tel"
                            name="phone"
                            id="phone"
                            placeholder="+0 000 00 00"
                            onChange={numberHandleChange}
                        />
                    </label>

            )}
```

I tried importing Alert from Bootstrap and Reactstrap to use inside else function, it doesn't work.
Alert is not showing up, and also the input field lets print letters too.

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Lema, I am of the view that if you control the state of the input, it's better you assign the value of that state when you update it with the onChange event handler.

> A few notes: On line 5: you declare the `number` state and always update it when the input changes on line 11, but you don't assign it anywhere. You also import the reactstrap `Alert` but are not using it, instead using the browser alert(am wondering if you think they might be connected!). The browser alert, hijacks the react state updates and pauses the other browser events, and once it's dismissed, we see the invalid value assigned to the form much as the handler regex caught it!

Better approach would be giving react total control of the DOM input <kbd>Comment: 5</kbd>. And also put an error piece of state <kbd>Comment: 2</kbd>, so when the value is invalid, you don't bother updating it but just update the error <kbd>Comment: 4</kbd>.

The problem though is that when you were assigning the `value={number}` on the input with what you set as the initial state of the number, a space `character =" "`, <kbd>Comment: 1</kbd> it failed at `e.target.value === "" || re.test(e.target.value`, and always returns the else error. *Maybe that's why you removed the value from the input in the first place*. So I updated that to set initial state to no character at all and it works okay.

---

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
// import { Alert } from "reactstrap";
import "./styles.css";

export default () => {
  const [number, setNumber] = useState(""); // 1. Note, no space between the quotes
  const [error, setError] = useState(""); // 2. Track the error in the input

  const numberHandleChange = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const re = /^[0-9\b]+$/;
    if (e.target.value === "" || re.test(e.target.value)) {
      setNumber(e.target.value);
      setError("");  // 3. Clear the error if input is valid
      console.log(e.target.value);
    } else {
      // alert("please check your phone number");
      // 4. Set the error on invalid input
      setError("❌ Only accept number characters between 0-9");
    }
  };

  return (
    <label htmlFor="phone">
      <h5>Phone</h5>
      <input
        type="tel"
        name="phone"
        id="phone"
        placeholder="+0 000 00 00"
        value={number} // 5. Give react total control over the input.
        onChange={numberHandleChange}
      />
      {error && <span className="error">{error}</span>}
    </label>
  );
};
```

[Link to updated Sandbox.](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-w59p6?file=/src/App.js:0-890)

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, this is exactly what I wanted to achieve. Marking your answer as correct.

Comment: Glad it was helpful. Happy coding

Answer (score 1):

Your input field is not bound to the number variable you declared with `setState`
Add `value={number}` as a prop of input.

You can't output a DOM element from your function.
Typically, you'd declare an error variable and conditionally output a React `Alert`.

For example, you can declare another state hook for 'isError` and set it in your else block to true.

Then you can use a ternary in your return statement. Something like,

`{isError? <Alert>Some text</Alert> : false}`

Or, the shorthand:
`{isError && <Alert>Some text</Alert>}`

Just a thought, what will dismiss this alert?
Also, you will need a React Fragment to wrap the new Alert element.

Depending on your version, the shorthand `<>` and `</>` will do the trick...

Answer (score 0):

The alert is shown on my screen and the logic of the code seems fine. Maybe you are somehow preventing popups? The codesandbox works as intended. What do you mean by the input field lets print letters? Generally, React uses Alert with `Alert`. You can import this. You can also use if and else statements with this.